# Using a proxy in httpclient, the connection is broken

Tags: c#, proxy, httpclient, squid, preflight

My project is based on .net 7.0, and I use httpclient to access the rest api service on the Internet, but this service needs to be accessed through a proxy server, so I set the proxy in the code as:

```
var webProxy = new WebProxy("address", false);
var proxyHttpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = webProxy,
    UseProxy = true
};
ICredentials credential = new NetworkCredential("user001", "psw");
webProxy.Credentials = credential;
httpClient = new HttpClient(proxyHttpClientHandler);
```

Next, I wrote a get method to read the test webpage, and the html content of the webpage can be returned normally, which shows that the proxy and the program are working normally.

But when I call the rest api through the post method, it often fails (not every time, which also confuses me), and prompts an error of "the connection is broken".

I checked the log of the proxy server and found that there are actually two requests for each post. I guess the first request is a preflight request. For this request, the proxy server log shows a 407 error, and no username is displayed, indicating that Credential is not carried. For the second request, the log shows that it is forwarded normally, and  username is displayed, indicating that Credential information is carried.

My proxy server is ubuntu+squid. The two log information is as follows：

```
TCP_DENIED/407 3954 CONNECT api.xxx.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
TCP_TUNNEL/200 2653 CONNECT api.xxx.com:443 user001 HIER_DIRECT/100.18.6.192
```

I think there are three solutions:

1. Let the preflight request also carry Credential.
2. Forbid httpclient to send preflight request.
3. Modify the squid configuration, ignoring the authentication of preflight request.
   But these three solutions, I have not found a corresponding method.